# Exporting VHD file from OS-Disk to storage account

Tags: azure, powershell, migration, storage, vhd

I am trying to export VHD file from managed os-disk from southeast Asia to East Us location but gives me error 403 Authentication Failed "Copy failed when reading the source".
I am a global admin for tenant and Owner on subscription. Please find the screenshot and script for the same.

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionName "Prod-Sub"
$RGName = "r-d-server-RG-2" 
$DiskName = "r-d-server2-OSDisk-13052020"
$StorageAccount = "migratestorageserver2"
$STGKey = "dgosW21YW1kCyPLfhjf7Qhj14XMvRqqFB9Usp4jnjOPjJLRdwhfqBa3mJxHDnE7i479BUFQSK0vefgv/GKaYUA=="
$ContainerName = "migratecontainer"
$VHDName = "r-d-servermigrated.vhd"
$sas = Grant-AzureRmDiskAccess -ResourceGroupName $RGName -DiskName $DiskName -DurationInSecond 9600 
-Access Read 
$destContext = New-AzureStorageContext –StorageAccountName $StorageAccount -StorageAccountKey $STGKey 
$blob1 = Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy -AbsoluteUri $sas.AccessSAS -DestContainer $ContainerName - 
DestContext $destContext -DestBlob $VHDName


#Retrieve the current status of the blob copy operation
$status = $blob1 | Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyState  

#Print out status  
$status  

#Loop until complete                                     

While($status.Status -eq "Pending"){
    $status = $blob1 | Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyState
    Start-Sleep 10
    ### Print out status ###
    $status
}
```

Comment: Do you still work on this problem? I didn't see any updates and you also didn't accept it.

Comment: Why not give any response? Do you want to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Most codes are right, I just need to recommend you turn into using the [Az module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-3.8.0). But the last while loop, it's not the right logic. The right logic is to get the fresh status list this:

```
While($status.Status -eq "Pending"){
    Start-Sleep 10
    ### Print out status ###
    $status = Get-AzStorageBlob -Context $destContext -Blob $VHDName -Container $ContainerName | Get-AzStorageBlobCopyState
}
```

And you should stop the VM before copy.